# Calcular cómo ha variado una columna de números a lo largo de una columna del tiempo

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matemáticas

Tengo un marco de datos con una columna de número (tipos de interés, tipo FLOAT) y una columna de fecha (en formato aaaa-mm-dd, tipo OBJECT). ¿Cómo puedo calcular cómo ha variado la tasa de interés promedio de un préstamo a lo largo del tiempo?

```
>>> result[['int_rate','issue_d']]
    int_rate    issue_d
0   12.69   2015-10-01
1   9.17    2015-10-01
2   6.89    2015-10-01
.   ....    ....
```

Aquí está el conjunto de datos si puede ser útil:

```
    Unnamed: 0  id  member_id   loan_amnt   funded_amnt funded_amnt_inv term    int_rate    installment grade   sub_grade   emp_title   emp_length  home_ownership  annual_inc  verification_status issue_d loan_status pymnt_plan  url desc    purpose title   zip_code    addr_state  dti delinq_2yrs earliest_cr_line    inq_last_6mths  mths_since_last_delinq  mths_since_last_record  open_acc    pub_rec revol_bal   revol_util  total_acc   initial_list_status out_prncp   out_prncp_inv   total_pymnt total_pymnt_inv total_rec_prncp total_rec_int   total_rec_late_fee  recoveries  collection_recovery_fee last_pymnt_d    last_pymnt_amnt next_pymnt_d    last_credit_pull_d  collections_12_mths_ex_med  mths_since_last_major_derog policy_code application_type    annual_inc_joint    dti_joint   verification_status_joint   acc_now_delinq  tot_coll_amt    tot_cur_bal open_acc_6m open_act_il open_il_12m open_il_24m mths_since_rcnt_il  total_bal_il    il_util open_rv_12m open_rv_24m max_bal_bc  all_util    total_rev_hi_lim    inq_fi  total_cu_tl inq_last_12m    acc_open_past_24mths    avg_cur_bal bc_open_to_buy  bc_util chargeoff_within_12_mths    delinq_amnt mo_sin_old_il_acct  mo_sin_old_rev_tl_op    mo_sin_rcnt_rev_tl_op   mo_sin_rcnt_tl  mort_acc    mths_since_recent_bc    mths_since_recent_bc_dlq    mths_since_recent_inq   mths_since_recent_revol_delinq  num_accts_ever_120_pd   num_actv_bc_tl  num_actv_rev_tl num_bc_sats num_bc_tl   num_il_tl   num_op_rev_tl   num_rev_accts   num_rev_tl_bal_gt_0 num_sats    num_tl_120dpd_2m    num_tl_30dpd    num_tl_90g_dpd_24m  num_tl_op_past_12m  pct_tl_nvr_dlq  percent_bc_gt_75    pub_rec_bankruptcies    tax_liens   tot_hi_cred_lim total_bal_ex_mort   total_bc_limit  total_il_high_credit_limit  revol_bal_joint sec_app_earliest_cr_line    sec_app_inq_last_6mths  sec_app_mort_acc    sec_app_open_acc    sec_app_revol_util  sec_app_open_act_il sec_app_num_rev_accts   sec_app_chargeoff_within_12_mths    sec_app_collections_12_mths_ex_med  sec_app_mths_since_last_major_derog hardship_flag   hardship_type   hardship_reason hardship_status deferral_term   hardship_amount hardship_start_date hardship_end_date   payment_plan_start_date hardship_length hardship_dpd    hardship_loan_status    orig_projected_additional_accrued_interest  hardship_payoff_balance_amount  hardship_last_payment_amount    disbursement_method debt_settlement_flag    debt_settlement_flag_date   settlement_status   settlement_date settlement_amount   settlement_percentage   settlement_term
0   1040017 NaN NaN 14000   14000   14000.0 36 months   12.69   469.63  C   C2  Receiving Dock Worker   9 years MORTGAGE    40000.0 Not Verified    2015-10-01  Charged Off n   NaN NaN debt_consolidation  Debt consolidation  166xx   PA  17.07   0.0 Jun-2001    1.0 NaN NaN 5.0 0.0 5848    90.0    15.0    f   0.0 0.0 6057.790000 6057.79 4091.51 1556.41 0.0 409.87  73.7766 Oct-2016    469.63  NaN Jul-2018    0.0 NaN 1   Individual  NaN NaN NaN 0.0 0.0 119776.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 6500.0  NaN NaN NaN 4.0 23955.0 2167.0  90.0    0.0 0.0 141.0   172.0   3.0 3.0 1.0 3.0 NaN 3.0 NaN 0.0 3.0 3.0 8.0 8.0 6.0 3.0 8.0 3.0 5.0 NaN 0.0 0.0 2.0 100.0   100.0   0.0 0.0 123292.0    29809.0 6500.0  25992.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN N   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN Cash    N   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   1050463 NaN NaN 1000    1000    1000.0  36 months   9.17    31.88   B   B2  Portfolio Manager   1 year  MORTGAGE    80000.0 Verified    2015-10-01  Fully Paid  n   NaN NaN credit_card Credit card refinancing 949xx   CA  12.51   0.0 Oct-1967    3.0 NaN 22.0    9.0 1.0 7634    37.2    32.0    w   0.0 0.0 1021.730000 1021.73 999.99  21.74   0.0 0.00    0.0000  Feb-2016    27.85   NaN Feb-2017    0.0 NaN 1   Individual  NaN NaN NaN 0.0 0.0 53994.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 20500.0 NaN NaN NaN 4.0 5999.0  12866.0 37.2    0.0 0.0 188.0   575.0   4.0 4.0 3.0 4.0 NaN 1.0 NaN 0.0 3.0 3.0 6.0 16.0    9.0 6.0 20.0    3.0 9.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 100.0   0.0 1.0 0.0 80788.0 53994.0 20500.0 60288.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN N   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN Cash    N   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   1056254 NaN NaN 13000   13000   13000.0 36 months   6.89    400.75  A   A3  mailhandler 10+ years   RENT    70000.0 Not Verified    2015-10-01  Fully Paid  n   NaN NaN debt_consolidation  Debt consolidation  751xx   TX  21.72   0.0 Oct-1996    0.0 NaN NaN 16.0    0.0 11113   24.4    23.0    w   0.0 0.0 14425.915413    14425.92    13000.00    1425.92 0.0 0.00    0.0000  Oct-2018    401.38  NaN Jan-2019    0.0 NaN 1   Individual  NaN NaN NaN 0.0 316.0   93918.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 45600.0 NaN NaN NaN 10.0    5870.0  28646.0 26.9    0.0 0.0 227.0   60.0    7.0 5.0 3.0 7.0 NaN 7.0 NaN 0.0 7.0 8.0 8.0 8.0 8.0 10.0    10.0    8.0 16.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 4.0 100.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 141771.0    43988.0 39200.0 42191.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN N   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN Cash    N   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
...
```

#### Actualizacion

```
result2 = result.set_index("issue_d")
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 6))
result2.int_rate.plot()
```

Sin embargo, parece que los préstamos se prestan una vez al mes. Es mi culpa, al pedirles que muestren sus tasas de interés mensualmente, tengo este extraño gráfico que no me aporta mucho.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto, voy a hacer una nueva pregunta para saber ¿Cómo ha variado la tasa de interés promedio de un préstamo a lo largo del tiempo?

Mientras tanto, estos préstamos se pueden ver [aquí](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Po7GVbU0M13AAwWfY_a5yvK-XwHePVTB) (300MB).

Comment: Convierte la columna `issue_d` a tipo fecha (con `pandas.to_datetime()` y úsala como index (`result = result.set_index("issue_d")`). Una vez hecho eso, un simple `result.int_rate.plot()` te dará lo que buscas.

Comment: @abulafia Muchas gracias, sin embargo, tengo un pequeño problema cuando trato de mostrar. Es mi culpa, me muestra la variación de todos los préstamos a lo largo del tiempo y me gustaría saber cómo uno ya varía, tendría más sentido. Desafortunadamente, no sé, por el momento, qué me permite conocerlo en el conjunto de datos.